# ReactJS - Toggle visibility without re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I use ReactJS + nextJS + Semantic-UI-React

I have my json response like this.

```
[
    {
        "artist": "Cardi B",
        "dob": "01/01/1990",
        "albums":[
            {
                "title": "Invasion of privacy",
                "year": "2018"
            }
        ],
        "country": "usa"
    },
    {
        "artist": "Michael Jackson",
        "dob": "01/01/1950",
        "albums":[
            {
                "title": "Thriller",
                "year": "1981"
            },
            {
                "title": "Blood On The Dance Floor",
                "year": "1995"
            }           
        ],
        "country": "usa"
    }
]
```

I would like to show each artist in a table row. Albums of the artist would be shown when some cell of the artist row is clicked .

I have 2 components. One for artist and one for the album. `AlbumTable` component is basically another table wrapped inside `<Table.Row>`. Basically the below code works just fine.

```
toggleVisibility(index){
    let oldSt = this.state.AlbumStatus;
    oldSt[index] = !oldSt[index];
    this.setState({AlbumStatus: oldSt});
}


renderResult(){
    let rows = this.props.artists.map((r, index) =>{
        return(
             <Table.Body key={index}>
                  <Table.Row >
                        <Table.Cell>{r.artist}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell>{r.dob}</Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell onClick={() => this.toggleVisibility(index)}>+</Table.Cell>                 
                        <Table.Cell>{r.country}</Table.Cell>                            
                  </Table.Row>
                  <AlbumRow result={r.albums} hiddenStatus={!this.state.AlbumStatus[index]} />
              </Table.Body>
        );
    });
    return rows;
}


render(){
    return(
      <Table > 
            <Table.Header >
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.HeaderCell >Artists</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell >Dob</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell >Albums</Table.HeaderCell>                                    
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
            {this.renderResult()}
       </Table>             
    );      
}
```

My requirement is to show the Albums only if the '+' sign of the artist row is clicked. I am able to toggle the visiblity using above code.

**Issue:**

If I click the '+' sign of 'Michael Jackson' row, his corresponding albums are displayed. however all the artist's albums are also re-rendered. Is this expected?? Will it cause any performance issue for large data sets? What is the best approach without affecting performance much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a huge issue unless you notice that things get laggy with large datasets. When it comes to performance, measure first if you think you have a problem ([read more on measuring React performance](https://building.calibreapp.com/debugging-react-performance-with-react-16-and-chrome-devtools-c90698a522ad)). Don't waste time trying to over-optimize until you know that you have a problem.

Once suggestion might be to break off each row into a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent):

```
import React, { PureComponent } 'react';

class AlbumTableRow extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        const {
            key,
            artist,
            dob,
            country
            albums,
            albumsHiddenStatus,
            onToggleVisibility,
        } = this.props;
        return(
            <Table.Body key={key}>
                <Table.Row >
                    <Table.Cell>{artist}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{dob}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell onClick={onToggleVisibility}>+</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell>{country}</Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>
                <AlbumRow result={albums} hiddenStatus={albumsHiddenStatus} />
            </Table.Body>
        );
    }
}

export default AlbumTableRow;
```

PureComponents *should* only re-render when the prop **values** change. You should then change the parent component code like so:

```
getOnToggleVisibility = (index) => () => this.toggleVisibility(index);

renderResult(){
    let rows = this.props.artists.map((r, index) =>{
        return (
            <AlbumTableRow
                key={index}
                artist={r.artist}
                dob={r.dob}
                country={r.country}
                albums={r.albums}
                albumsHiddenStatus={!this.state.AlbumStatus[index]}
                onToggleVisibility={this.getOnToggleVisibility(index)}
            />
        );
    });
    return rows;
}
```

Note that I added a `getOnToggleVisibility` method, which takes that index and returns an `onToggleVisibility` function that knows the proper index to use.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I think you are confused. '+' sign would be present on the ArtistRow which toggles the AlbumTable. The problem here is setState which resets the whole array - it causes all the artists albums to re-render!

Comment: Even though it does not solve the actual problem, it helped with a hint to redesign the whole component in a such way that it performs much better than I expected. So I accept this as an answer.